# What is the zip file created when Delphi compiles with Developer ID for MacOS

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

When I compile with a macOS platform and a configuration of "Developers ID" (notarized), the deployment creates a zip file in the scratch-dir with same name as the project. It appears to   be the .app zipped up. If I un-compress, it also shows as notarized. I can not find any information on the expected use of this file. While I could distribute it, I would think a dmg file would be more familiar.